# Broken apt trying to install Cassandra

Tags: apt, dpkg, cassandra

While trying to install Cassandra on Ubuntu 13.10, the installation crashed and now I'm stuck with broken (?) apt-get.

Here is the output of an apt-get install -f:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 414 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cassandra (2.0.9) ...
vm.max_map_count = 1048575
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 12, in <module>
    from optparse import OptionParser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 25, in <module>
    from urllib import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    from functools import partial
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 12, in <module>
    from optparse import OptionParser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
dpkg: error processing cassandra (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cassandra
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any apt-get command that I run outputs pretty much the same result...

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get -d install packageName`?

Comment: `dpkg --configure -a --force-all`

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. None output any thing special. Even installing other stuff gives the same error...

Comment: Why are you using an EOL release of Ubuntu? There isn't going to be much anyone can do for you here except advise you to upgrade to the latest LTS release.